# What is the connection with the headline and the text?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The Headline is:

> "It’s Not Your Parents’ Hip Replacement Surgery"

I read it through:

[*New York Times* Hip Replacement Surgury](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/18/well/live/hip-replacement-surgery.html)

although with some limitation but I can only make any sense without the negatory thus:

> "It’s Your Parents’ Hip Replacement Surgery"

what am I missing?

Comment: The *not* means that it isn't the kind of hip replacement surgery that one's parents would have; that is, it's something more advanced and fashionable. This turn of phrase comes from the advertisement that led to Oldsmobile going out of business: "Not your father's Oldsmobile."

Comment: @FeliniusRex at first I thought it was about something new too, but the article still refer to procedure to be a surgery

Comment: Of course it is a surgery. It is a hip replacement surgery.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiom "This is not your *older person*'s [object]". For example

> This isn't your grandma's rose garden

Meaning it is a new exciting type of rose garden, that has been planted to appeal to young people. Or

> Not your father's Oldsmobile

Meaning it is a new and exciting model of (the American car maker) Oldsmobile.

And although the article is unreadable for me (unless I pay), that seems to be the meaning.  It is about new technologies, particularly robotics, used for hip replacement surgery.

There is an irony, because while it is done with very modern technology, it is still intended mostly for older people.

Comment: it still refer to the procedure as to be a surgery